# Clear laravel queued jobs in Redis for Laravel 5.x/6.x/7.x/8+

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-artisan

How to **empty all queued jobs in a redis database** for a given queue in Laravel versions previous to **Laravel 8** ?

Sometime when your queue is filling in a dev environment you want to clean all queued jobs to go back to a fresh start.

Laravel doesn't provide an easy way for doing so before 8.x and Redis database aren't the most intuitive to do this task manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Laravel 8+** makes it easy with the following command :

```
php artisan queue:clear redis --queue=queue_name
```

where queue name is the name of the specific queue you want to clear. default queue is called `default`

**For laravel < 8** I created this artisan command specific to redis:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class QueueClear extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'queue:clear {--queue=}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Clear all jobs on a given queue in the redis database';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $queueName = $this->option('queue') ? $this->option('queue') : 'default';
        $queueSize = Queue::size($queueName);
        $this->warn('Removing ' . $queueSize . ' jobs from the ' . $queueName . ' queue...');
        Redis::connection()->del([
            'queues:' . $queueName,
            'queues:' . $queueName . ':notify',
            'queues:' . $queueName . ':delayed',
            'queues:' . $queueName . ':reserved'

        ]);
        $this->info($queueSize . ' jobs removed from the ' . $queueName . ' queue...');
    }
}
```

In the `app/Console/Commands/Kernel.php` file add the folloowing command:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\QueueClear'
];
```

Then, depending on your queue you can call it that way:

**Default queue**

```
php artisan queue:clear
```

**Specific queue**

```
php artisan queue:clear --queue=queue_name
```